# Obtaining moments from the *inverse* of the moment-generating function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have a moment generating function $z=\phi(t)$ whose inverse has the following form for integer $k>0$

$$t=\frac{z}{(1+z)^{k+1}}$$

How would I get the moments?

Code below uses `Solve` to get the moment generating function followed by `SeriesCoefficient` go get moments. This works for $k=1$, but fails for $k>1$, any tips?

```
k = 1;

phi = First@SolveValues[z/(1 + z)^(k + 1) == y, z];
exact[s_] := SeriesCoefficient[phi, {y, 0, s}];

n = 1000;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}]/Sqrt[n];
mat = Nest[sample . # &, sample, k - 1];
empirical[s_] := 
  With[{square = mat . mat\[Transpose]}, Tr[MatrixPower[square, s]]/n];


nf[val_] := NumberForm[val, {3, 2}];
vals = Table[{nf@empirical[s], exact[s]}, {s, 1, 5}];
TableForm[vals, TableHeadings -> {{}, {"empirical", "predicted"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does using [`InverseSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries) work, e.g., ``InverseSeries[Series[z/(1+z)^3,{z,Infinity,6}],y]`` for ``k=2``?

Comment: Ah, yes, `InverseSeries` works!